# Wordpress attack regarding .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, xss, code-injection

I get an Internal server error when I try to access my site. Server is actually working fine, I have access like usual in the ftp mode.
For some reason I am being attacked, likely an XSS attack, that affects my .htaccess file making it look like that:
lots of ##:

[image]

which results to a gigantic length of that line, making the server rendering it as a length overflow and not dipsplaying the site.
When I try to modify that file, it has changed the permissions, so i first need to change them and then modify it. After I have deleted all the "#" site works fine.
After some time, the same thing happens.

I have the latest wordpress installation, and have also installed wordfence.
How can I stop this?

EDIT: Server admin says it hasn't to do with the server, because there are other wordpress sites with no problem.

Comment: Mate, `####` is a comment. Anything starting with a `#` is a comment in `.htaccess`. You may safely remove it.

Comment: Of course it's a comment, and of course I can remove it as I am stating in my question. The problem is that it keeps reappearing.

Comment: Looks like to me, your server is compromised. You need to really talk to your provider and explain the issue to sysadmin as soon as possible.

Comment: As i am writing this, it seams that more "#" have been added magically to the file, 5 minutes after I deleted them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the FTP password, there are no more unwanted file edits, thus no more overflow server issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

1) You/Some Plugin creator have created some bad PHP files in your WordPress installation which are writing to your .htaccess (maybe creating an endless loop) - this would probably be custom scripts as most Plugins in the WordPress repository have been tested

2) Most likely your WordPress installation and/or server have been compromised/hacked. **Your server admin definitly should take your request seriously.**

Steps to perform in case of hacked WordPress:

1) Make a backup

2) remove all files from the server and your database

3) change all passwords (WordPress, FTP, Provider-Login, database etc. etc.)

4) Make a fresh installation of WordPress

5) Check your database sql for any malicious code before putting the database backup in again

6) Check your WP-Content Folder for any malicious code before you put it on the server again

In many cases some PHP file is corrupted by an attacker which may write to .htaccess